# LINQ to XML XElement Unreachable Code Detected?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to grab values from an XML file using LINQ in c#, and it is giving me a warning saying

***"class System.Xml.Linq.XElement Represents an XML Element. Warning: Unreachable code detected"***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace BDiamond
{
    public class Login
    {
        private string email ;
        private bool isValid = false;
        private string bdConfigFile = "BDiamond.xml";

        public bool VerifyEmail(string e)
        {
            string email = e;

            //Grab element values that match the Email attribute in XML file
            XElement root = XElement.Load(bdConfigFile);
            IEnumerable<XElement> list1 =
                from el in root.Elements()
                where el.Attribute("Email") != null
                select el;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the warning associated to?

Comment: this code doesn't compile. show us some compilable code

Comment: Not sure what you mean by compiable code... If it compiled I wouldnt have an issue? It is VS2010, and the line of code giving warning is XElement root = XElement.load(bdConfigFile);

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a ConsoleApplication, and it didn't give me any warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you provided your actual code, but what you are missing is a return statement, and it's not a *warning* it's an *error*. Clearly this code doesn't generate any warning. You can add a *return* statement to the end of your method like this:

```
return list1.Any();
```

Or you can do that in one statement:

```
public bool VerifyEmail(string e)
{
     string email = e;

      //Grab element values that match the Email attribute in XML file
      XElement root = XElement.Load(bdConfigFile);
      return root.Elements().Any(el => (string)el.Attribute("Email") == email);
}
```

I guess you should compare the value of `Email` attribute with the parameter `email`, otherwise it doesn't make any sense.And also if you know which element owns the `Email` attribute, you can use this:

```
return root.Descendants("ParentElement")
      .Any(el => (string)el.Attribute("Email") == email);
```

Instead of iterating over all the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer.. I think it might of been the return statement, and the code review was helpful as well! Cheers!